# cargar objetos a una lista

Tags: c#

Eh estado intentando cargar objetos a una lista tengo esta clase que me carga los datos y uno de ellos es una de tipo List tengo implementado de esta manerala clase el cual recibe los datos

```
public class Insertar_Inscripcion_Cliente
{
    public Persona Persona1 { get; set; }
    public Cliente Cliente1 { get; set; }
    public Huella Huella1 { get; set; }
    public Inscripcion Inscripcion1 { get; set; }
    public Pago Pago1 { get; set; }
    public List<DetalleInscripcion> ListaDetalleInscripcion { get; set; }

}
```

desde esa clase llamo a otras clases de esta de esta manera

```
public  class DetalleInscripcion
{
    public string CodInscripcion { get; set; }
    public string CodDisciplinaTipoInscripcion { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaVencimiento { get; set; }
}
```

ahora desde el Form trato de cargar de esta manera en el for hago recorrer 
el datagridview y asi primero carga el objeto DetalleInscripcion y despues lo intenta añadir al objeto lista

```
   void InsertarVerificado(bool valor, string Efectivo, string Cambio)
    {
        Insertar_Inscripcion_Cliente param = new Insertar_Inscripcion_Cliente();
        DetalleInscripcion paranD = new DetalleInscripcion();
        for (int i = 0; i < dg_DIsciplinas.Rows.Count; i++)
        {                
            paranD.FechaVencimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(dg_DIsciplinas.Rows[i].Cells["FechaVencimiento"].Value);
            paranD.CodDisciplinaTipoInscripcion = CodDiscipliaTipoInscripcion;
            paranD.CodInscripcion = "2";
            param.ListaDetalleInscripcion.Add(paranD);
        }  
    }
```

Perso me salta un error al tratar de cargar el Lista el mensaje de error
[image: Perso me salta un error al tratar de cargar el Lista el mensaje de error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica aquí:

```
public List<DetalleInscripcion> ListaDetalleInscripcion { get; set; }
```

Como estás usando una [propiedad autoimplementada](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) y nunca la inicializas, entonces su valor por defecto será `null` y por esa razón te da esa excepción.

En C# 6 y versiones posteriores, te permite inicializar una [propiedad autoimplementada](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) de esta manera:

```
public List<DetalleInscripcion> ListaDetalleInscripcion { get; set; } = new List<DetalleInscripcion>();
```

Otra solución, sería crear el objeto de tipo `List<DetalleInscripcion>` en el constructor de la clase `Insertar_Inscripcion_Cliente`:

```
public class Insertar_Inscripcion_Cliente
{
    public Persona Persona1 { get; set; }
    public Cliente Cliente1 { get; set; }
    public Huella Huella1 { get; set; }
    public Inscripcion Inscripcion1 { get; set; }
    public Pago Pago1 { get; set; }
    public List<DetalleInscripcion> ListaDetalleInscripcion { get; set; }

    public Insertar_Inscripcion_Cliente()
    {
       ListaDetalleInscripcion =  new List<DetalleInscripcion>();
    }
}
```